# SharePoint site and designer keep asking for credentials

Tags: credentials

I'm not a SharePoint admin so I'm very new to this.
My SharePoint site keeps asking for username/password.  The site is obviously listed as local intranet.
I am also not able to open the site in SharePoint designer. It asks for my credentials 3x then displays an error that says:

> The folder isn't accessible. The folder may be located in an unavailable location, protected password, or the filename contains / or .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turned out I had Kerberos set up on the site.  You can change this in central admin.  [The answer on this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/cfe8cda0-706a-4fb1-8c22-839fe3a7eab0) steps you through the process.

Answer (score 0):

Look for authentication providers in IIS management console for your SharePoint site
(IIS MMC/your site/authentication/windows authentication/providers)

NTLM should be first or only option